# Sum of elements of an array java

Tags: java

Write a method called sumArray that takes an array of integers as a parameter, and returns an integer equal to the sum of all elements in the array. I keep getting zero for my output.

```
public static int sumArray( int[] sum) {
    int add=0;
    for(int i=0; i< sum.length; i++) { 
       sum[i]+= add;
    }

    return add;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You put your addition in the wrong way, it should be :

```
add += sum[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int sumArray( int[] sum) {
    int add=0;
    for (int i=0; i< sum.length; i++) {
        add+=sum[i];
    }
    return add;
}
```

Your variable on the left is being added with each element of sum.

Answer (score 1):

shortest way i know would be :

```
int add=Arrays.stream(sum).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add `add` variable that equals zero to each element of `sum` array, and then return `add` variable that still equals zero. If you swap the places of variable `add` and array element `sum[i]`, you will begin to add `sum[i]`'s value into `add` at each iteration.

Please make a search before you ask such a trivial question.

Comment: Definitely a trivial question--but what would one search for, and how?  "How to prevent your output from being zero"?

Comment: "sum + array + java"?